# Trigger ansible job from Bitbucket

Tags: ansible, bitbucket, webhooks, ansible-tower

Have an issue with setting up Bitbucket webhook.

As the reuslt, I need to configure webhook in Bitbucket, which will trigger Ansible job with authorization.

I have a Bitbucket repository and proceed to "Repository Settings" -> "Webhooks". On this page I set up Name and URL (https://ansible-tower.test.com/api/v2/job_templates/3984/launch). This URL should launch ansible job. But when I pressed "Test connection" button on "Edit webhook" page in Bitbucket I got 401 Error, because I'm not authorized to perform this job. As the result I need to send authorized request to Ansible. How can I do this?

#### Update

I can perform this request via curl, but need to set up webhook.

Comment: The following documentation should help you: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/administration/oauth2_token_auth.html#using-oauth-2-token-system-for-personal-access-tokens-pat

Answer (score 1):

In BitBucket, in the repo that you'd like to set up hook, click the "gear" icon - "Hooks" - "HTTP Request Post-Receive Hook", enable it and fill out the form, make sure to keep the trailing '/' after 'launch' in the endpoint URL.( in your case, the url would be "https://ansible-tower.test.com/api/v2/job_templates/3984/launch/"), put in username and password which has permissions to launch the job on tower, save, quit and done.